# MYSQL Query help, I thikn this should be simple... but I can't get it

Tags: mysql, join

So I join two tables in a query, let's use below as an example:

```
SELECT property.address, property.city, property.state, property.zip, unit.name    
FROM   property, unit
WHERE  unit.propertyID = property.id
```

This table can return a list of all properties that have a matching unit in the unit table.

My problem is, if I have properties that DO NOT have units, I still want those to show up, with "N/A" or "NULL" or something in place of the unit name...

As of now, it just completely excludes those properties that don't have at least 1 matching unit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to update your query to working order:

```
SELECT property.address, property.city, property.state, property.zip, unit.name    
FROM   property
left join unit on property.id = unit.propertyID
```

Better way to write it, using aliases:

```
select p.address, p.city, p.state, p.zip, u.name
from property p
left join unit u on p.id = u.propertyID
```

To populate a value when there is no unit:

```
select p.address, p.city, p.state, p.zip, IFNULL(u.name,'N/A') as unitName
from property p
left join unit u on p.id = u.propertyID
```

Comment: ugh I swear i've tried a left join already...maybe I joined it backwards though.  Thanks man.

Comment: @Shackrock just realized mine was backwards since I just took your where clause up... Edited to correct.  In a left join, the table on the LEFT is the one that will show records even if the table on the right has no match.

Comment: @fosco gotcha, works like a charm.  So, what if I wanted to insert a value if there was no match in the table to the right, is that possible?

Comment: @Shackrock that would not be valid as it is an alias... it could probably be `as name` to keep the same output column name.

Comment: @Shackrock your output column does not include the table name, and the output of the IFNULL() function no longer has any association with the original table or column.

Answer (score 0):

Use LEFT OUTER JOIN :

```
SELECT p.address, p.city, p.state, p.zip, u.name    
FROM property p LEFT OUTER JOIN unit u ON p.id = u.propertyID
```

Comment: You know that `outer` is implied automatically in a left join, right?

Comment: It's not INNER that is implied? I always believed that! :p

Comment: `join` = inner, `left join` = outer.